# Why is my laptop keyboard malfunctioning after running boot-repair?

Tags: grub2, keyboard, laptop, dell, boot-repair

So, after using boot-repair to fix (reinstall) a Grub issue, some of the keys on my laptop have ceased to work. The specific keys are <kbd>;</kbd>,<kbd>'</kbd>,<kbd>/</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>. I tried swapping back to the live CD I ran boot-repair off, but the issue persists. I checked the region, and it seems to be the one I always used. I'm using an external keyboard to type this.

How can I revert to the situation to where the keys on my notebook were functional?

Comment: All the keys you describe are in the region of the numeric keys on most laptop keyboards. My best guess is that you have NumLock turned on or some other "feature" of that keyboard. Please provide the exact details of your machine.

Comment: Well, this machine is a Dell Inspiron 1150 model. The keyboard has been replaced before, if that helps. Also, tried messing with NumLock. No dice.

Comment: And now, more keys are going out. <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>backspacw</kbd>, <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd> are out now, too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be hardware related.

Comment: @gertvdijk unless i misread the scope of the site, Ubuntu related hardware questions are OK here... so why is this offtopic?

Comment: @ThomasW. If hardware is failing, Ubuntu software is irrelevant. Here we have a keyboard failure. All evidence shows this is the keyboard itself to blame.

Comment: True.  However, that doesn't make the question itself as offtopic, but that the answer would correctly state "This is just coincidental, as it seems your keyboard is broken, and you will need to contact the manufacturer to repair the system."